# Call a method from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning python and I'm trying to make a program with objects, if you could help me I'd be very very glad.

I'm trying to call a method of class Character (the method attack) from a dictionary (the dictionary actions).

In the line with the problem `play[1]` is an object created before; when the user types "attack", the line `play[1].actions[char]()` should call the method "attack" of the play[1] object, but it gives error saying that the object play[1] has no attribute "actions". How can I access the method?

I've understood why `play[1].actions[char]()` doesn't work but I can't figure out another way to do it.

```
class Character:
 ......
   def attack():    
   print("something")

actions={"ATTACK":attack, "DEFEND": defend, "MAGIC":magic}

[...] ##in the rest of the code play[1] is created as Character

char=input("Choose Attack, Defend or Magic\n").upper()
if char in actions:
   print("ciao")
   play[1].actions[char]()  ##Houston, we have a problem
   break
```

Comment: `def attack(self):`

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize the play variable?

Comment: `actions` doesn't look like a method of `Character` but you want to call it from `play[1]` which is an instance of `Character`

Comment: Thanks everybody!! now it works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`actions` is just a dictionary. It is not a property of the `Character` class. What you want is to refer to the action that *is* a property, referencing it from the `actions` dictionary:

```
getattr(play[1], actions[char])()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hasattr` and `getattr`:

```
if hasattr(play[1], actions[char]):
    getattr(play[1], actions[char])()
```

or without the use of `hasattr`:

```
def dummy():
    pass

getattr(play[1], actions[char], dummy)()
```

This makes sure that there will not be an error if `play[1]` does not have the method `actions[char]`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but if the code is Python 2, this is worth a read: https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/